# Split Factorial of n

Tags: number-theory, factorial, products

How can I split integers up to n into two groups such that the difference of the product of each group is as low as possible? Is there a way to optimize the selection for each group in order to ensure a lower gap between them?

Comment: Got a feeling this is equivalent to a NP problem and, therefore, hard. For a heuristic, sort the integers and start pairing at the ends and from the middle.

Comment: You can take logs and ask to split them into two groups with closest sum.  This emphasizes that the later numbers are close together. I guessed you should use the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) to separate them, but it fails.  For $n=8$, the groups are $1,4,6,7$ and $2,3,5,8$ with products $168, 240$, but $5,6,7$ and $1,2,3,4,8$ gives $210,192$ which is better and probably hard to beat.

Comment: Is there a way I could approximate or find what the optimal gap would be equal to?

Comment: See OEIS sequence  http://oeis.org/A200743

Comment: @RobertIsrael Here's an OEIS sequence of what OP is explicitly asking for; http://oeis.org/A038667

Comment: These sequences only give me values. Is there a way of obtaining even a rough approximation of the gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ross Millikan is right.  Take logs of the numbers and look for a partition of the logs into two nearly sums.  This problem is NP-hard.  See the Wikipedia page for the partition problem.

Comment: The general problem is NP-hard, but there is structure here that may make it not so.  I don't know.